# Scheduling a UK visa biometrics appointment

Tags: visas, uk, applications

When scheduling a biometrics appointment, is there a maximum period for scheduling the appointment for - eg one month?

Comment: Does an UK visa holds a travelers biometrics? :o

Comment: @Joren Vandamme Can you clarify what your comment means?

Comment: @Traveller, when you request a visa for the UK, do you need to give them your fingerprint or go trough a eye scanner?

Comment: @Joren Vandamme For a UK visa, biometrics means fingerprints and photograph eg https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/apply

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are referring to a Standard Visitor visa, when you submit the application online a calendar of available biometric appointment dates will appear. As far as I recall, the dates published are normally within a three-week period. Once you’ve booked an appointment, you can change it online before the actual date.